# Materialize modal black background

Tags: angular-cli, materialize

I just added materialize on Angular-cli and I wanted to add a modal as well. When it pops-up, it has a strange black background behind the modal. I inspected it and it's from "modal" class.

[Here is how it looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIi9Z.png)

Here is the modal html code:

```
<div id="modal1" style="background-color: white">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is where I added the modal:

```
<div id="tab-modal" class="modal" materialize="modal"
 [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: false}]" [materializeActions]="modalActions">
 <app-order-dish [modalActions]="modalActions" ></app-order-dish>
</div>
```

Tell me what else should I include to resolve this problem. Thanks!